# How to make an image zoom with respect to its frame (ImageJ)

Tags: java, user-interface, imagej

So I thought I ask a new question which is an extension of my old question. So I was able to get the contents out from the ImageJ window into my JInternal frame which is inside my desktop pane. But the image will not zoom as the frames size is enlarged. I have found a couple of ways mainly using the zoom class in ImageJ but it will not scale to fit the frame. So I was wondering if anyone knows what I am doing wrong. The zoom in is working and so is the zoom out but the set to zoom and scale to zoom don't work and I have no idea why. Thank in advance.

Here is part of my code:

```
public class CustomGui extends ImageWindow implements InternalFrameListener, ComponentListener, ActionListener{

    public CustomGui(ImagePlus imp, String title, JDesktopPane desktop, final JMenuItem save, JWindow win, JMenuItem fft) {
        super(imp);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setCall();
        img = imp;
        save.setEnabled(true);
        fft.setEnabled(true);
        //this.title = title;
        this.win = win;
        this.fft = fft;
        this.save = save;


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        ImageCanvas c = new ImageCanvas(imp);
        c.getImage();

        //panel2.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(c.getImage())));
         m = new ImageWindow(img);

        Image n = new Image();
        frame = new MyInternalFrame(title, img, save,m);
        //ImageCanvas c = m.getCanvas();
        ImagePlus im = new ImagePlus();
        im.setImage(img);


        //ImageRoi roi = ImageRoi();
        //panel.add(c);
       //   frame.add(m.getContentPane());
        m.centerNextImage();

      //This is where I try to use the zoom class.
        img.getCanvas().setScaleToFit(true);

        //ImageCanvas nu = new ImageCanvas(img);
        //nu.setScaleToFit(true);

     //I set arg to "scale" but it doesn't work, even when I put it in component resized listener.
        Zoom z = new Zoom(img);
        String arg = "orig";
        z.run(arg);

        //m.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        //m.setLocationAndSize(true);
        //m.setLocationAndSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        panel.add(m.getCanvas());
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        frame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
                frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {

        }
       frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);  
       frame.addComponentListener(this);
       //win.add(desktop);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals(SHOW)){
            save.setEnabled(true);
            frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);
        }

        System.out.println("beingg called");
    }

      public void setCall(){
            called = true;
        }

        public void setCallF(){
        called = false;
        }

        public boolean getCall(){
        return called;
        }



      //This is where the internal frame is resized.
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Rectangle r = frame.getBounds();
    //      int h = (int) r.getHeight();
    //      int w = (int) r.getWidth();
    //      m.resize(w, h);
        //m.getCanvas().unzoom();
        //m.setLocationAndSize((int)r.getWidth(), (int)r.getHeight(), (int)r.getWidth(), (int)r.getHeight());
        m.getCanvas().fitToWindow(r);
        System.out.println("resized- the real one");

    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        frame.show();

    }

    }
```

I also added a constructor to the zoom class (this is part of the zoom class):

```
    /** This plugin implements the commands in the Image/Zoom submenu. */
   public class Zoom implements PlugIn{

ImagePlus imp;
public Zoom (ImagePlus img){
    imp = img;
}

public void run(String arg) {
    //ImagePlus imp = WindowManager.getCurrentImage();
    //ImagePlus imp = img;
    if (imp==null)
        {IJ.noImage(); return;}
    ImageCanvas ic = imp.getCanvas();
    if (ic==null) return;
    Point loc = ic.getCursorLoc();
    if (!ic.cursorOverImage()) {
        Rectangle srcRect = ic.getSrcRect();
        loc.x = srcRect.x + srcRect.width/2;
        loc.y = srcRect.y + srcRect.height/2;
    }
    int x = ic.screenX(loc.x);
    int y = ic.screenY(loc.y);
    if (arg.equals("in")) {
        ic.zoomIn(x, y);
        if (ic.getMagnification()<=1.0) imp.repaintWindow();
    } else if (arg.equals("out")) {
        ic.zoomOut(x, y);
        if (ic.getMagnification()<1.0) imp.repaintWindow();
    } else if (arg.equals("orig"))
        ic.unzoom();
    else if (arg.equals("100%"))
        ic.zoom100Percent();
    else if (arg.equals("to"))
        zoomToSelection(imp, ic);
    else if (arg.equals("set"))
        setZoom(imp, ic);
    else if (arg.equals("max")) {
        ImageWindow win = imp.getWindow();
        win.setBounds(win.getMaximumBounds());
        win.maximize();
    } if (arg.equals("scale"))
        scaleToFit(imp);
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) If you provide a [minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating your problem, you make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @JanEglinger I added the code, I have tried a couple of things. I hope its not to messy.

Answer (score 1):

In [`Zoom.java`](http://fiji.sc/Zoom.java), I don't see any constructor taking an argument. Are you sure you're importing and using [`ij.plugin.Zoom`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/plugin/Zoom.html)?

The standard ImageJ GUI allows to fit to scale using the `ij.plugin.Zoom` class. Run the following JavaScript snippet in [Fiji's script editor](http://fiji.sc/Script_Editor) to switch between *normal* and *scale to fit* modes:

```
zm = new Zoom();
zm.run("scale");
```

The status bar of the ImageJ main window (and the source of `Zoom.java`) also provides the hint that pressing *alt* while resizing the window will result in the image scaling to the window size.

Sorry that I don't spend the time fiddling with your code: it's not really a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yeah I forgot to say this but I created a constructor for it because I need to pass my image that is opened in my customized gui. I also tried the alt but it didn't do anything. I don't know if this is problem but I don't use there image window I have my own internal frame.

Comment: Hm, I guess then I have to leave it to someone else to help you further. If you created your own customized GUI, that's a little too involved for me. However, to avoid wasting time of those willing to help, I'd suggest that you also provide your _customized_ `Zoom` class, so that others can actually reproduce what you are doing.